# How to check if an UIElement is a Panorama or not

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a code like this

```
        foreach(UIElement iue in layout.Children)
        {
            if (iue is Panorama)
            {
                //some code
            }
        }
```

but this is always false.

I also tried

```
        foreach(UIElement iue in layout.Children)
        {
            if (iue.getType() == typeof(Panorama))
            {
                //some code
            }
        }
```

with no success.

Comment: Are you sure the child properties are of type Panorama?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes one of them is.

Comment: To be sure that you have at least one Panorama item in the Childrens make a `MessageBox.Show(iue.GetType().Name);` inside the for but outside the if to see what the children types are.

Comment: Please post some XAML to check

Comment: @verdesrobert just checked the xaml and found that it was not a Panorama but a inherited UserControl PanoramaFullScreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the XAML again and found that there was no Panorama but a UserControl that was inherited from Panorama with name PanoramaFullScreen (to have full screen PanoramaItem).

Thank you everyone for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test app and your code should work. If you have double checked everything else keep in mind that the `Children` property will return top level elements only. If your `Panorama` control is a child element then you will need to get to it using the `Children` property of the parent control. Another thing to check is that the namespace of the control you used in the line `typeof(Panorama)` is `Microsoft.Phone.Controls`. You can do this by hitting F12 when you cursor is on the word `Panorama`.

Comment: This is not working for me. As iue has become UIElement. So its type is also UIElement

Comment: GetType() will return the exact runtime type of the current instance. So if the element is a `Panorama`, 'iue.GetType()` will return `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Panorama` instead of `System.Windows.UIElement`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)

Comment: just checked the xaml and found that it was not a Panorama but a inherited UserControl PanoramaFullScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change in your code. try this, may will help you.

```
foreach(UIElement iue in layout.Children)
        {
            if (this.IsPanorama(iue ))
            {
                //some code
                //Panorama control
            }
            else
             {
               //not aPanorama control
             }
        }
```

//just check whether a UI element is panorama or not

```
private bool IsPanorama(UIElement element)
{
    bool isPanorama =false;
   try{
       Panorama p = (Panorama)element;
        isPanorama = true;
       return isPanorama ;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        isPanorama = false;
        return isPanorama ;
      }
}
```

Comment: just checked the xaml and found that it was not a Panorama but a inherited UserControl PanoramaFullScreen.

Comment: When casting p can be null if not of that type